# CSS Zengarden - show the :before of a div and hide the div itself, show on hover the div

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm currently working on a design for CSS Zengarden (https://www.csszengarden.com/) as part of a university project. Because of this, I cannot change the html code and can only use what has been provided as part of the html code. However, I can add classes to the html-elements. Java Script is also not allowed.

I want the image "Brief.png" to show initially and once a user hovers over the image, the `div` with its text inside should appear. Is this possible?

To improve the animation, I would like to show a gif as soon as the cursor hovers, before transitioning to the div's text content after a short delay.

I'm not looking for a solution to my problem but rather input on how to figure it out myself.

```css
/** ### letter animation ### **/
.letter::before{
    align-items:normal;
    content: url('Brief.png');
    
}

.letter:hover::before{
    content: url('Brief.gif');

}

/** ## Hide & Show content of div ## **/
.hide{
   opacity: 0;
}
.hide:hover{ 
    overflow: auto;
    width: 33.33%;
    /**height: 50vh;**/
    margin: 2em auto;
    box-shadow:   -15px 0 0 0 rgb(83, 60, 30),
                 15px 0 0 0 rgb(83, 60, 30),
                 0 -15px 0 0 rgb(83, 60, 30),
                 0 15px 0 0 rgb(83, 60, 30);
    padding: 1%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 221, 177);
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="preamble letter hide" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
        <h3 class="center">The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
        <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
        <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>, and the major browser creators.</p>
        <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
    </div>
```

What I've come up with for now:

- The animation on `hover` from png to gif works only if the div isn't hidden.
- The `transition-delay` trigger for the div works.

I also tried using the sibling-selector (`.letter:hover::before + .hide`), but because the image is a `:before` they aren't siblings, as I learned.

Comment: Make the children invisible rather than the div itself.

Comment: But if I do that just the hovered children apears on hover. Is there an option that they all apear if any of them gets hovered?

Comment: Why aren’t you sensing when the parent gets hovered?